# WPF: One-way IValueConverter

Tags: wpf, ivalueconverter

From what I've been told, I need to create an `IValueConverter` to do my custom formatting. The problem is my formatting is one-way, there is no legitmate `ConvertBack` implementation.

So, how do I handle one-way `IValueConverter`s. (If it helps, this is for a read-only control.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All the examples from Microsoft simply throw a [NotSupportedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception.aspx) or a [NotImplementedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception.aspx) (the former makes more sense) from the `ConvertBack` method.

As you say, if the converter is one-way then chances are you'll be using it on a read-only control like `TextBlock`, so the `ConvertBack` method won't be getting called anyway.